# Can't get Kerberos realm for hive jdbc

Tags: hive, kerberos

I am using hive in Kerberos environment, and get the following issue:

```
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://xx.xx.xx.xx:10000/default;principal=hive/emr-header-1.xxx@EMR.46727.COM
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://xx.xx.xx.xx:10000/default;principal=hive/emr-header-1.xxx@EMR.46727.COM
21/01/12 23:00:35 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to xx.xx.xx.xx:10000
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://xx.xx.xx.xx:10000/default;principal=hive/emr-header-1.xx@EMR.46727.COM: Can't get Kerberos realm (state=08S01,code=0)
```

The special thing for my cluster is that krb5.conf is not in /etc/krb5.conf, instead it is in another location. I have already export KRB5_CONFIG as the new path, but it still doesn't work, what do I need to do for using the custom krb5.conf ? Thanks

Comment: JAAS config issues are silently ignored. Duh. You must set a debug flag to understand what really happens at run-time: `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

Comment: And that's something that shoud be in the HortonWorks - er, Cloudera - knowledge base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, I can specify the custom krb5.conf via specifying java properties `java.security.krb5.conf`, e.g. -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/myconf/krb5.conf

Answer (score 0):

sometimes
`export KRB5_CONFIG=/etc/krb5/krb5.conf` is not working!

so do a soft link to the default krb5.conf location

`rm -rf  /etc/krb5.conf && ln -s /etc/krb5/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf`

the `/etc/krb5/krb5.conf` is my custom `krb5.conf` file